# Facebook iOS SDK: How do I send a status post message to a test user?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.1

I've created a test user with the instructions [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/).

How do I send a status post request to this test user account?

I tried logging in as this test user under **Settings**. I can log in successfully.
But when I click on the **Log in with Facebook** button in my app,  Facebook returns an error saying

> The Facebook server could not fulfil this access request:
>   Invalid application 123xxxx

Answer (score 0):

As i understand from your question there are 2 different problems here.

**First**, you want to use your account to post to a testUser wall. Try this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"somekey", @"someobject" nil];

[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/feed", testUserFbId] // here you set in whose post you wanna do the action, in this case it is yourself
                                 parameters:params
                                 HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              id result,
                                              NSError *error) { /* Your code here */ }
```

**Second**, you can't login to your app using testUser account. This is a broader problem, and could have many causes.

- Check your .plist file to see if the is any error on fbId or any of the configurations for facebook.
- Check on facebook if your application is configured correctly.
- Remember that if your application is in sandbox mode only users allowed can see posts.
- Also, can you log in with your own user?

Let me know if i am on the right path here.

Comment: I've edited my question to make it more clear. This solution you proposed will still post to my own account from the looks of it. Key thing is to post a status updated to a **test user** account.